# Sorting problem in Java

Tags: java, sorting

I am having some trouble sorting some arrays and getting an error by the compiler when I do try so.  I have also tried doing it as Arrays.sort but, no luck.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class CH6PA
{
    private static double difficulty;
    private static int score;
    private  double[] average = new double[7];

    public static void main(String[]args)
    {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in);

        do
        {
            System.out.println("Enter the level of difficulty (1.2-3.8)");
        difficulty = keyboard.nextDouble();
        }
            while (difficulty<1.2 || difficulty>3.8);


        int[] judge = new int[7];


        for(int i = 0; i<judge.length; i++)
        {
        System.out.println("Enter the difficulty score for each judge (0-10)");

            System.out.println("Enter the score for judge" + (i+1));
            judge[i]=keyboard.nextInt();
    while(score > 0 && score <=10);
        }

sort(judge, judge.length);
System.out.println("Average = " + (judge[3] + judge[4] + judge[5]));

}
}
```

Comment: rather than telling us that you get a compilation error, you should tell us *what* the compilation error message is, and *what line* the error is on.

Comment: This looks like a homework question to me.  Assuming that, **hints** would be more appropriate than complete answers.

Answer (score 0):

while(score > 0 && score <=10); seems to be wrong.What is the value of score?

And why two nested loops in which while() loop doesn't do anything as you have applied ;.

Answer (score 0):

Score has no value assigned to it, and therefore you're comparing null values.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you meant:

```
do {
    System.out.println("Enter the score for judge" + (i+1));
    judge[i]=keyboard.nextInt();
} while(judge[i] > 0 && judge[i] <=10);        }
```

Right now, `judge[i]` would be any `int` read from `stdin` (if compiled)

The line:

`while(score > 0 && score <=10);`

has no meaning right now, so you get a compiler error.